# This part of my code is suppose to append inputs from a verified user into file user.txt however nothing is appended

Tags: python, list, file-io

This part of my code is suppose to append  inputs from a verified user into file user.txt however nothing is appended. I had converted the same file in code before this code block to a list but then closed it when I was done so that shouldn't affect it.

```
while True:

   if username_pword in login_list:
         menu = input('''Select one of the following Options below:
r - Registering a user
a - Adding a task
va - View all tasks
vm - view my task
e - Exit
: ''').lower()
   if menu == 'r':
       
        pass

        new_user = input("Please enter a username to register: ")
        n_password = input("Please enter your password to register: ")
        confirm_password = input("Please confirm your password: ")
        if n_password == confirm_password:
            rf = open("user.txt", "a")
            rf.write(new_user + "," + " " + n_password + "\n")
```

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you sure this is the code you're running?  You might want to include the output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Files are edited when they are closed so, you need to have a `rf.close()` or you can use a with statement like so :

```
while True:

   if username_pword in login_list:
         menu = input('''Select one of the following Options below:
r - Registering a user
a - Adding a task
va - View all tasks
vm - view my task
e - Exit
: ''').lower()
   if menu == 'r':
        new_user = input("Please enter a username to register: ")
        n_password = input("Please enter your password to register: ")
        confirm_password = input("Please confirm your password: ")
        if n_password == confirm_password:
        with open("user.txt", "a") as rf:
                    rf.write(new_user + "," + " " + n_password + "\n")
```

It should close the file when the with is finished